# how to construct a Rect object in opencv 3 in python?

Tags: python, opencv, module, opencv3.0, cannot-find-symbol

I tried to create it by writing the command:

```
myRect = cv2.Rect(p1, p2)
```

but it does not find it. It writes:

```
Cannot find reference 'Rect' in 'imported module cv2'.
```

thanks for helping!

to make it clearer:
I don't want to draw a rectangle on an image. I want to create a Rect object to apply methods on, such as area().

Comment: thanks, but I don't want to draw a rectangle on an image. I want to create a Rect object to apply methods on, such as area().

Comment: There is none in the python interface... You can use a tuple in place where a cv::Rect is needed. e.g. `(0,0,100, 100)` this is a "rect" with the top left corner in (0,0) and a size of 100 width and height

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('input.jpg')
myRect = img[280:340, 330:390]
```

`280:340`, `330:390` means: get a rectangle that begins at 280th row and 330th column and ends at 340th row and 390 column. So coordinates of the rectangle would be: `(280,330), (280,390), (340,330), (340,390)`